# OnMouse over selected table row class changing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am changing table row class on select with jquery. But I mouseover It is changing class which expecting other than the unselected rows. For selected row class should change on mouse over.

How to do that?

```
 $('#<%=grdDataSource.ClientID%>').delegate('tr', 'click', function () {          
        $('#<%=grdDataSource.ClientID%> tr').not(this).removeClass('SelectedRowStyle');
        $(this).toggleClass('SelectedRowStyle');
    });
```

Comment: Where is mouseOver code??

Comment: I believe you should be using on() rather than delegate now(). delegate() was superseded by on() from jQuery 1.7 afaik. https://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: it is asp.net gridview. Can I check condition if table row has class`SelectedRowStyle` keep that class on mouseover?

Answer (score 0):

You can add and remove classes using the following jQuery functions

```
$('#waypointsTable tr').hover(
   function() {
        $(this).addClass('className');
   }, 
   function() {
      $(this).removeClass('className');
  }
);
```

And then you can define your classes in CSS to perform specific styling. You can name your CSS class as selected for easy understanding.

Now, I would like to make a suggestion, you should look at Bootstrap and use it for easy styling. It will ease up your tasks, including this one.

Check this out: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables

Comment: I have to check if css class is `SelectedRowStyle` I should not changed this

Comment: what do you need to do if the class is present?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if a particular element has a particular class, you can use hasClass() function of JQuery

```
$( "element" ).click(function() {

    if ( $( this ).hasClass( "className" ) ) {

        /* Do some stuff (add or remove styling or animation) */


});
```